# Cannot select all elements except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all the elements of a page except one, inside a function:

```
$('#sidebutton').click(function () {

if (!$('.sidemenu').hasClass("current")) {
    prevScrolPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    scrollTo = 0;
} else {
    scrollTo = prevScrolPos;
}

$('.hidelem').toggleClass("hidden");
$('.sidemenu').toggleClass("current"); 
$('html,body').scrollTop(scrollTo);
});
```

It works when I use a simple class selector (.hidelem), but doesn't when I use something a bit more complicated (for example, `$("*:not(.sidemenu)").toggleClass("hidden");` or `$("*").not(".sidemenu").toggleClass("hidden");`); these just lead to a blank window.

Could you tell me what I'm missing here?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/et978wjw/5/ (full functionality is missing but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: Why do you use the `&&` operator there? `$('.sidemenu').toggleClass("current")` returns a jQuery collection(an object), objects are considered truthy in JavaScript and the second expression is executed.

Comment: well if you add a class to body and it is set to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` your whole page would disappear. `$("*:not(.sidemenu)")` would include `body` and `html` tags. Suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net and point out what you want

Comment: Also, your `prevScrolPos` variable doesn't get set in your `else` condition only for your `if` condition.

Comment: Vohuman, the answer to your question is "because I don't know a thing about JS". Thank you for the information, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Gary, the main part of the function was created for me by a kind fellow user here in stackoverflow. I myself don't really know what would be the best way to implement this thing. Can you tell me exactly what I should change?

Comment: charlietfl, I see your point. What if I used $("body *:not(.sidemenu)")? Because I've tried that too and it didn't work. Demo added, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Well you still need to explain expected behavior . It's impossible to tell what you want this code to do. Use `@` before user names to ping them in comments

Comment: @charlietfl, I've written what I want it to do inside an HTML comment on jsfiddle. When users click on the button, all the elements on the page will get hidden except for the sidemenu.

Comment: In that case put everything inside one container, except the side menu. Then body has only 2 children. Then toggle the other container

Comment: @charlietfl, That's actually what I thought as a last resort. The question however is, why won't it work by adjusting the selector?

Comment: Approach is really bad as it has to hide potentially hundreds or more of elements. Just doesn't make sense

Comment: @charlietfl, Hiding all elements on a page except for one or two has been done done successfully by a lot of people, regardless of the number of elements that are being hidden in each case. Just Google it. There is some other reason why it doesn't work. Anyway, thank you for your replies.

Comment: Sure, but it makes no sense and isn't the proper way to approach this. You could try `$('body').children().not('.sidemenu')`. Assumes `sidemenu` is a child of body

Comment: I admit that I don't really know about what's proper or not in JS, but choosing which elements to affect by using the right selectors instead of creating new HTML elements when we just want to select something, make perfect sense to me. Besides, the idea behind creating more powerful selectors is to avoid messing up with HTML elements and classes every time we want to create a specific hook. As for the snippet, it doesn't work, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you may be skipping `.sideMenu` with `$("body *:not(.sidemenu)")`, but you are not skipping its parent DIV. If you hide an ancestor, you hide all its descendants too. You also do not skip any descendants, so the children of `.sidemenu` are also hidden

So you need to exclude anything that is an ancestor of .sidemenu with `:not:(has())`, then exclude the sidemenu itself, then exclude any children of sidemenu:

```
$("#container :not(:has(.sidemenu)):not(.sidemenu):not('.sidemenu *')").toggleClass("hidden");
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/et978wjw/8/

You really should direct the hide/show at something more specific though. Perhaps a wrapper div around everything you want hidden? I added one for the demo.

Now having said all that, your selection process is quite complicated. You would be better off simply adding a class to all the things you want to toggle instead and just toggle those (you already have `nodisplay` on the divs, so I used that for now).

e.g. just this:

```
$(".nodisplay").toggleClass("hidden");
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/et978wjw/9/